# issue on displaying integer value to zero when DB value is NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hi all I have written the following to display the integer values from database to the gridview column as follows

```
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblTotalReplies" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("TotalReplies")==System.DBNull ?  "0" : Convert.ToInt16(Eval("TotalReplies")).ToString() %>'></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Replies</li>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

But I am getting an error as `System.DBNull' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context` can some one help me how can I display `0` when I am having null value in database. I don't want to bind using `rowdatabound` or some other

Comment: why can't you use ISNULL(yourColumn,0) in your SQL Script.

Comment: change your sql script to handle null values. isnull([field],0) will return zero if the field is null, otherwise it returns the field value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare with [DBNull.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTotalReplies" runat="server" 
     Text='<%#Eval("TotalReplies") ==System.DBNull.Value ?  "0" : 
           Convert.ToInt16(Eval("TotalReplies")).ToString() %>'>
</asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Replies</li>
```

DBNull is the type, while the Value property

> Represents the sole instance of the DBNull class.

Answer (score 2):

It's true. It is a type. Maybe you're looking for the static [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx) field on it?

```
Eval("TotalReplies")==System.DBNull.Value
```

> Represents the sole instance of the [`DBNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.aspx) class.

---

Ravi's comment was pointing out that if your SQL currently looks like this:

```
SELECT TotalReplies, ...
```

Then you could change it to:

```
SELECT ISNULL(TotalReplies,0) as TotalReplies, ...
```

I'd usually use `COALESCE` rather than `ISNULL`, it would look identical in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The `System.DBNull` type has a static field `Value` to which you should compare:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblTotalReplies" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("TotalReplies") == System.DBNull.Value ?  "0" : Convert.ToInt16(Eval("TotalReplies")).ToString() %>'></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Replies</li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```